# Database reference became null when I pushed on a spinner button

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

In my main **activity (A)** I open a database (SQLite) calling the specific class, and storing the "db-pointer" to a variable. It works: I can load/save data from/to the database.

For some jobs, I must start another **activity (B)**. This one opens the database to do some operations to the database (especially create a new record in it).

When I close (B), Android restarts and resumes the main activity. I check the "db-pointer", and it is NOT null.

In the main activity there is a spinner-button. If I push on it, and choose a different value, the "db-pointer" became null. The "onItemSelected()" must call the database to find data.
**Why did the "db-pointer" become null?**

CODE to open the database and create the "db-pointer":

```
dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open();
```

LogCat of the error:

```
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442): Process: com.example.Traffic, PID: 1544202-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.Traffic/databases/dbtrip
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1156)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at com.database.trip.DbAdapter.fetchVehiclesByCod(DbAdapter.java:240)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at com.example.Traffic.Mappa.vehicleParameters(Mappa.java:937)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at com.example.Traffic.Mappa.access$1(Mappa.java:936)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at com.example.Traffic.Mappa$1.onItemSelected(Mappa.java:717)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:896)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:51)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:864)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
02-22 23:11:25.560: E/AndroidRuntime(15442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's not a `NullPointerException` in your stack trace. How did you arrive to the conclusion that your pointer had become null? Did you actually look at it? To me it looks like the object still exists, it has just been closed and invalid for further use.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.Traffic/databases/dbtrip`. You must (re)open the database before using it.

Comment: @MATTI i checked it in onRestart, onResume, ... and in the onItemSelected it becames "not open" (i wrote null, but the real situation is "NOT OPEN"). I check it with isOpen().

Comment: @BOB i added the code to reopen the db if it is not open in the onItemSelected, and the error is solved, BUT why the "db-pointer" became "NOT OPEN" only in the onItemSelected ? While in onRestart, onResume, ... it is open ? THX :)

Comment: @Adamz: Don't write "null" if you don't mean null, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this exception that it can not reopen the database. This happens when you close the DBHelper and reuse it.